# Is there a way to check for admin rights in Windows with Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to build a basic starter script that figures out what OS I am running on and if any special modules need loaded. As far as Linux is concerned I am able to check for root by looking at the effective uid `$>`is there a way to do a similar operation on windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Win32](http://metacpan.org/module/Win32)
might help you to get username in Windows.

Comment: Awesome, I found a function called `Win32::IsAdminUser()` that should work perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( system("NET SESSION >NUL 2>&1") ) {
    ...
}
```